# Tag synonyms (refactor -> refactoring)

Tags: discussion

I think we should make [refactor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactor) a synonym of [refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and did it. Thanks!